# mpdf not working in exeoutput

Tags: php, pdf, desktop-application

I am trying to convert PHP Web application to desktop application using **ExeOutput for PHP 2018**. I have tried compiling with PHP 5.6, 7.1 and 7.2

I have tried using mpdf 6.x and 7.x

in all the cases, I get a grey window with a popup message : "Failed to load pdf document."

The same code works fine when I run the same application in a web browser.

Following is my code:

```
require_once '../mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($a);
$mpdf->SetJS('this.print();');
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Please help

Comment: Download the file, open it in an editor, and check if there are any warnings above the PDF data. Any output will make it invalid for a PDF viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the latest mpdf library (7.x) from github, make it using composer so that you get the vendor directory and then try compiling application with 7.x version.
Use the same pdf generation code. 
Things will go fine.